# Как сделать так, что бы при наведении цвет текста становился другого цвета (ошибка в коде)?

Tags: css

У меня есть меню с выпадающим меню. Сейчас у меня при наведении на основное меню цвет текста меняется, но как только курсор переходит ниже, в выпадающие меню, то цвет основного меню меняется обратно. так не должно быть. Посмотрите пожалуйста на мой код, потому что я не могу найти ошибку). Спасибо все кто поможет!

```css
/* Menu
    ==========================*/

.menu {
  background: #BDBDBD;
  /* text-align: center; */
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.topmenu {
  padding: 0 51px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

nav a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: .2s linear;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.active {
  /* font-weight: bold; */
}

.topmenu>li {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.topmenu>li>a {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
}

.a {
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 15px 15px;
}

.topmenu>li>a:hover {
  color: #184fa3;
}

.active:after,
.submenu-link:after {
  color: inherit;
}

.topmenu>li:hover {
  color: #184fa3;
}

.submenu li a:hover {
  color: #DA1111;
}

.submenu {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #184fa3;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 5px rgba(1, 102, 174, 0.22);
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(10px);
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}

.submenu li {
  position: relative;
}

.submenu a {
  background: #fff;
  color: #1c1c1c;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.submenu .submenu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

nav li:hover>.submenu {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0px);
}
```

```html
<nav class="menu">
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="topmenu">
      <li><a href="" class="a">рекламная продукция</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
          <li><a href="">Визитки</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Листовки</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Многостраничные изделия</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Плакаты</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Упаковка</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Конверты</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Папки</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Календари</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Пакеты</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Календарные сетки</a></li>
          <li><a href="">СТР формы</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Изделия нестандартных размеров</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="" class="a">картонная упаковка</a></li>
      <li><a href="" class="a">флексо печать</a></li>
      <!-- <li><a href="" class="a">Производственные мощности</a></li> -->
      <li><a href="" class="a">контакты</a></li>
      <li><a href="" class="a">о нас</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: А как это исправить?

Comment: Кажется понял о чём речь

Comment: Поможете решить?

Comment: А тут нет ошибки. Цвет у вас меняется при наведении курсора. Как только курсор убрали - цвет меняется обратно. CSS работает правильно.

Comment: Но как сделать так, что бы цвет текста оставался синим, когда курсор перемещается на выпадающее меню?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На самом деле всё просто. Надо заменить это:

```
.topmenu>li>a:hover {
  color: #184fa3;
}
```

на это:

```
.topmenu>li:hover>a {
  color: #184fa3;
}
```

то есть отслеживать курсор над `li` элементом, а окрашивать саму ссылку